# s function usage error- code generation

Tags: matlab

My s function is build with SfunctionBuilder block from already existing c source code & tlc file is also generated for it. It takes two nubers as input & output the sum of two numbers.

```
void add(unsigned char *ip_1,unsigned char *ip_2,unsigned char *result)
{
    *result = *ip_1 + *ip_2;
}
```

I have integrated a matlab s-function in my model.

I am getting following error while generating code, for the model.

> Error: Simulink Coder Error in block: "one_mdl_extention/One
>   Model/S-Function Builder", block type "S-Function": Block output
>   output_1 uses custom storage class, level 2 but the compliance level
>   of this block is only 1; use a different block or a different custom
>   storage class, level 1 or lower

How to resolve this error ?

I have made a simple c function & used s-function builder to create s function, now how can i decide it as a level-1 or level-2 s function ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Only use Level 2.

Level 1 S-Function block still exists in Matlab primarily for legacy reasons, Level 2 is a improved version. There is nothing you can implement in a Level 1 S-Function which you can not implement in a Level 2 S-Function. Other way round, there are many features missing in the old Level 1 S-Function.

There is only one case, where Level 1 S-Functions have an advantage over Level 2 S-Functions, in simulation they run faster. Most users never create Models of a complexity, that simulation time really matters.

Comment: but why my c source code is converted into level-1 s-function, by s-function builder block ?

Comment: how can i specify that level-2 s-function to be generated by s-function builder ?

Comment: I don't have any reference, but I assume the S-Function builder is only capable of generating Level 2 S-Functions, so there is nothing to configure. I assume you reused the created code with a S-Function block, which is level 1. Pick the corresponding level 2 block and it should work.

Comment: Yes you are right i reused the mexw32...  i have generated  generated s function (sfunc_call_add_function.mexw32) from s function block & i am using it in another model by specifing the name in "s function system block".